# How angular and vue updates there binding expression without replacing any html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

From more then 1 years I am trying to find how angular and vue updates data inside bindings without  replacing any element . How can i do this using javascript please give me short idea.

They updates :-

let **a** be one variable  where I have used it inside binding like this **{{a}}** when variable **a** have new value or updates anything value of **a** inside binding expression also changes dynamically. we can also use this bindings as :- (attribute value dynamically changing)

```
          <span class="{{a}}"></span>    .......(1)
```

Yes I have my one idea that I can replace **{{a}}** this binding expression with something like this :-

```
            <span id="a"></span>
```

But what's on attribute cases like above example (1)??

Question that i want to know about all this things:-

1) How can I do something like this changing binding expression's value dynamically without effecting any other html elements in three cases mentioned below:-

```
case 1 :-  <span id="{{a}}"></span> 
case 2 :-  <span>{{a}}</span>
case 3 :-  <div id="hello"><input type="text">{{a}}</div>
```

In third case I don't want to update by re-rendering whole element of **id** hello.

Please comment and answer down your queries on this topic.